# How to ge thet data from WCF Ria Service method that returns IQueryable<> using ChannelFactory

Tags: wcf, wcf-ria-services

I have a WCF RIA Service with methods that return IQueryable<>. I want to access this methods using ClannelFactory from a 
console application. I have an interface on the client that matches the the methods in my RIA Service. When I run the server and
the client applications I can see that the server method is called and an IQuery<> object is returned. The problem is that on the 
client I can't get the data sent by the server. I can see that data actually comes by using Fiddler, but I think that the data can't be
deserialized to IQueryable.
For me the type of the data received doesn't matter. I'll be happy with just an array. But because the method in the
service returns IQueryable my OperationContract method on the client has the same type. 
So the question is how to get the data from the server, without changing the return type (IQueryable) on the server side?

Server side:

```
 public IQueryable<Customers> GetCustomers()
    {
        List<Customers> customersList = new List<Customers>();
        customersList.Add(new Customer())
    ...
        return customersList.AsQueryable();
    }
```

Client side:

```
 [ServiceContract]
    public interface CustoemrsService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        IQueryable<Customers> GetCustomers();

    }
```

And the ChannelFactory code:

```
var endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(_endpointAddress);
        var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<VfxSystemDomainServiceSoap>(new BasicHttpBinding());
        var channel = channelFactory.CreateChannel(endpointAddress);
        IQueryable<Customers> customersCollection = channel.GetVfxfopenQuery();
```

Comment: I just put together a simple WCF service with an operation that returns an IQueryable<int>, and I can receive it without issue.  What error are you receiving?

Comment: I haven't tried with IQueryable<int>. I don't get any errors just the result is empty collection, but I'm sure that the data comes because I can see it with fiddler. May be I have to use MessageInspector to get the data and make some custom deserialization.

Comment: It should work out of the box.  It sounds like you've copied the service interface - this is probably a namespace problem.  Check to make sure your namespaces match those that the service is using.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have the same namespaces on both sides. Also I can't get it work with IQueryable<int>. By the way It works with List<> of objects but the List must a property of other object.

Comment: So it works if you change it to `List`, but only if it's not a `List<Customer>`?  Please post your `Customer` data contract files - both the one the service is using and the one the client is using.  The **contract** namespace is likely different.